# flutter bloc implementations deviations

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to implement a similar app to counter app called japa counter , it has additional functionality to decrement counter . as well it maintains number of rounds and beeds . where when counter(beeds count)goes to 108 , rounds count get incremented and beeds count would initialise to zero. and so on..

initially i used setState for state management , it is quite straight forward to implement on '+' will call incrementCounter function of Counter class and on '-' will call decrementCounter function ,

to learn bloc , implemented the same using bloc , but as it is event , state model i can no more use incrementCounter , decrementCounter methods , i have to depend on constructor to change state as in the below link ,

https://github.com/gopiKrishnaPuligundla/japa_counter

is there a way i still use incrementCounter , decrementCounter.

my worry is bloc pattern is making the business logic quite deviated .i mean for increment i prefer incrementCounter than constructor with new values.

Comment: as well creating a new state object for every event is wierd , when i can achieve the same by just updating existing object fields

Answer (score 0):

this is what i understood about above questions on why .
Riverpod state management has similar concept stateNotifier.(it helps in notifying change in state of a notifier by creating new state object(immutable))
Riverpod also support changeNotifier (it helps notify change in object (mutable))

Riverpod suggests to use stateNotifier with immutable objects which is similar to bloc logic above mentioned , reason being we have handle for previous state as well , which is a great benefit in debugging , testing frameworks.

still changeNotifier adds performance as it wont create new objects.

as well they mention above select filters wont work in riverpod with changeNotifier